# How to use sqlite-net extension "https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions"?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net-extensions

How can I Implement sqlite-net extension "https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions"? I am downloading the code from the url but not getting how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably best to install it as a NuGet package into your project. Then follow the readme [here](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) same link you have posted.

If that doesn't work can you post some of the code you have tried